# iOS+SpriteKit: How to force portrait mode?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, orientation, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm currently working on a SpriteKit game for iOS 7+ and XCode 6. The game should always be presented in portrait mode. So far I have implemented these methods in my view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

This works fine as long as I start the app holding my iPad in portrait mode. It does not switch the orientation during game play.

But when holding the iPad in landscape orientation during the app is starting, the game is shown in landscape.

How do I force the app to be shown in portrait mode even if the device was held in landscape mode during startup ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To solve the app orientation issue

```
Go to your projects plist file (should be "YourApp-Info.plist")
Add a row and enter "Supported interface orientations"
Add the orientations that your app supports
```

Comment: Thanks. There were two entries in the Info.plist file. One generic "Supported interface orientations" and one specific for the iPad "Supported interface orientations (iPad)" which I had to adjust in order to solve the issue.

Comment: Why no other answers are saying this is beyond me.  Thankyou :)